# What experimental proof is available of symmetrical kinematical time dilation?

Tags: special-relativity

The twin paradox is a thought experiment. But real experiments (such as Hafele & Keating experiment and others like it) show asymmetrical kinematical time dilation!

If we look at other examples, such as GPS satellites and the ISS, surely we find asymmetrical kinematical time dilation? Note that, even though they are not in inertial frames, the total time dilation can be decomposed in a kinematical time dilation component (SR) and gravitational time dilation component (GR). In the H&K experiment they removed the gravitational time dilation component to make a prediction of the kinematical time dilation component, which was found to be asymmetrical when reunited.

So I would like to know if anyone can name a single conclusive experiment with atomic clocks  that proves the theory of symmetrical kinematical time dilation? The H&K experiment shows asymmetrical kinematical time dilation when the clocks are reunited.

Answer (score 2):

> So I would like to know if anyone can name a conclusive experiment that proves the theory of symmetrical kinematical time dilation?

For me, the most direct are the various experiments on the relativistic Doppler shift. Recall that the relativistic Doppler shift is the ordinary Doppler shift with time dilation and that the transverse Doppler shift is purely time dilation.

Emission and absorption spectra of fast moving atoms serve as precise frequency standards (the basis of atomic clocks). Emission based Doppler experiments have the moving atomic clock emit a frequency and then that frequency is detected in the lab, so they show time dilation of the atom in the lab’s frame. Absorption based Doppler experiments have the lab emit a frequency and then that frequency is detected by the moving atomic clock, so they show time dilation of the lab in the atom’s frame. Together time dilation of each frame as seen by the other.

However, as the question is about symmetrical time dilation it is essential that the atomic clocks be inertial and that spacetime curvature be negligible. Time dilation is only predicted to be symmetrical between inertial reference frames in flat spacetime. Experiments like H&K and GPS fail on both counts, so they do not apply.

The most famous inertial emission based experiment on the relativistic Doppler is the Ives and Stilwell experiment. And for absorption experiments saturated spectroscopy experiments are absorption based and inertial. Both of these experiments show the relativistic Doppler effect which is itself symmetrical and is directly based on symmetrical time dilation.

Thus, between the emission and absorption based studies of the relativistic Doppler shift we have direct experimental confirmation of time dilation in both directions. Further indirect information includes all experiments testing the first postulate.

Comment: Could you please note that relativistic transverse Doppler effect appears in different colors; redshift, blueshift or even no frequency shift at all. Please see fig. 3.7. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime or corresponding explanation here https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath587/kmath587.htm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am really looking for experimental evidence of symmetrical time dilation in the form of an actual physical clock (eg. atomic clock) and where the following holds:
Clock A is really slower than clock B
Clock B is really slower than clock A
I cannot see how the above conditions can hold in a real physical clock?

As noted in the body of the question, the H&K experiment, GPS satellites and the ISS all seem to prove asymmetrical kinematical time dilation?

Comment: @Piet Venter those experiments are atomic clocks. What do you think an atomic clock is? It is just a bunch of Caesium atoms that you do an absorption experiment on. That is why it is called an atomic clock. The experiments noted are indeed direct experimental evidence of symmetrical time dilation performed with moving atomic clocks.

Comment: With reference to: “The experiments noted are indeed direct experimental evidence of symmetrical time dilation performed with moving atomic clocks. “,

Can you explain in more detail how symmetry is observed in the experiments?
You would need to show:
Clock A is slower than clock B
Clock B is slower than clock A

As frequency is the inverse of time, I suppose an equivalent requirement would be:
Frequency of clock A is faster than frequency of clock B
Frequency of clock B is faster than frequency of clock A
Can you show the above?

Comment: With reference to: “The experiments noted are indeed direct experimental evidence of symmetrical time dilation performed with moving atomic clocks. “,

In the case of the H&K experiment, they observed one clock (the moving clock) to run slower than the other clock (after removing the effect of gravitational time dilation), hence asymmetrical kinematical time dilation! This result seems to conflict with the experimental results you mention?

Comment: @Piet Venter said “Can you explain in more detail how symmetry is observed in the experiments?” Yes, I added that to the answer. Please be aware that comments are for improving the answer, not for back and forth follow-up. If you want a discussion then you need to go to a discussion oriented forum. The H&K experiment does not conflict because it is non-inertial which breaks the symmetry. For discussion please go to physicsforums.com instead

Comment: @pietventer :  "Clock A is really slower than clock B Clock B is really slower than clock A I cannot see how the above conditions can hold in a real physical clock?"  Of course these statements cannot hold, because these statements are meaningless.  Here are the meaningful, correct and perfectly symmetric statements you should replace them with:  "**In clock B's frame**, Clock A is really slower than clock B.  **In clock A's frame**, Clock B is really slower than clock A."

Comment: With reference to: “"In clock B's frame, Clock A is really slower than clock B. In clock A's frame, Clock B is really slower than clock A." –“,

I don’t really see how this is going to help explain symmetrical kinematical time dilation in the H&K experiment?
When the airplane clock and the ground clock were reunited, they showed different kinematical time dilation- hence asymmetrical kinematical time dilation!

Comment: @Piet Venter I have added some additional material throughout the answer addressing the H&K and GPS experiment which are asymmetrical due to not being inertial and due to significant curvature. At this point I am done. There seems to be no community interest, either upvotes or downvotes for either answer, so it is not worth spending additional time

Comment: With reference to: “Absorption based Doppler experiments have the lab emit a frequency “,

There are two separate experiments involved here to show symmetrical kinematical time dilation, but the question assumed a single experiment. 
Although perhaps implicit, the question specifically asks about experiments with real atomic clocks in motion, such as the H&K experiment.

Comment: With reference to: “it is essential that the atomic clocks be inertial”,
No, it is not essential! If it was essential then the H&K experiment, which predicts kinematical time dilation, would be invalid!
The total time dilation is the sun of the gravitational (GR) and kinematical (SR) time dilation. In the H&K experiment they removed the gravitational time dilation and hence could predict the kinematical time dilation.

Comment: With reference to: “it is essential that the atomic clocks be inertial”,

If it really was only possible to experimentally test symmetrical kinematical time dilation in an inertial frame, it would be very difficult to test the theory- as even minute differences in gravity can be detected and would case non-inertial frames!

Comment: With reference to: “and that spacetime curvature be negligible.”,
Gravity is negligible nowhere, you will always have minute differences in gravity. If what you say are true then symmetrical kinematical time dilation could never be experimentally tested!

Comment: With reference to: “Time dilation is only predicted to be symmetrical between inertial reference frames in flat spacetime. “,
See above comments- you will never find truly flat spacetime, implying you could never experimentally test symmetrical kinematical time dilation!

Comment: With reference to: “Experiments like H&K and GPS fail on both counts, so they do not apply.”,

No, see above comments! In the H&K experiment they removed the gravitational time dilation and predicted the asymmetrical kinematical time dilation!

Comment: With reference to: “we have direct experimental confirmation of time dilation in both directions”,
No, see previous comments, they use two separate experiments.
Are you not wondering why experiments with real atomic clocks (such as H&K) show asymmetrical kinematical time dilation?

Comment: With reference to: “The H&K experiment does not conflict because it is non-inertial which breaks the symmetry.”,

See my previous comments above. If what you are saying is really true, then it would not be possible to find an inertial frame anywhere - you will always have minute differences in gravity! Hence you will always have asymmetrical time dilation!

Comment: I see that you did not mention Muons so far? Do they have symmetrical kinematical time dilation?

Comment: It looks like you did for not want an answer but rather to push some personal point of view.

Answer (score 0):

See the Wikipedia article [Experimental testing of time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_testing_of_time_dilation).

Muons hit the atmosphere at nearly the speed of light. They should decay in such a short time they do not reach the ground. They do reach the ground because of time dilation. The article mentions a number of tests, but does not mention that time dilation varies with time of day.

Similar experiments with particle accelerators have also measured time dilation more precisely. Also without a dependency on time of day.

Since the earth rotates, time dilation is the same in lots of different directions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although Muons does not really have a clock that we can read, let us suppose the following:
Clock A is on earth and clock B is ‘clock’ of Muon. We are somehow able to ‘read’ the Muon clock and compare it with a clock on earth.
So we can say Clock B is running slower than clock A.
Hence Clock A is running faster than clock B.
But then we necessarily have asymmetrical kinematical time dilation!

Comment: So I am really looking for experimental evidence of symmetrical time dilation in the form of an actual physical clock (eg. atomic clock) and where the following holds:
Clock A is really slower than clock B
Clock B is really slower than clock A
I cannot see how the above conditions can hold in a real physical clock?

As noted in the body of the question, the H&K experiment, GPS satellites and the ISS all seem to prove asymmetrical kinematical time dilation?

Comment: Muons do have a clock. They are formed in the upper atmosphere when cosmic rays collide with air molecules. They decay with a very short half life. The half life is so short that without time dilation muons should not reach the ground from the upper atmosphere, even at the speed of light. In general, a clock need not be an actual clock. It can be any physical process that proceeds at a known rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even if we take the half life of the Muon as a ‘clock’, how does it show symmetrical kinematical time dilation?
You need to show that the following holds to prove symmetrical time dilation:
Clock A is slower than clock B
Clock B is slower than clock A
Can you show the above?

Comment: It shows there is no directional dependence. As the earth rotates, time dilation stays the same. You measure momentum and number muons in space or the upper atmosphere. This tells you the rate of arrival and if they arrive uniformly on all sides of the earth. You measure the momentum and number of muons as you receive them on the ground. From this you get the fraction of muons that make it to the ground at each momentum. This tells you the half life at each momentum. From this you can see that time dilation varies as expected with velocity, and there is no directional dependence.

Comment: With reference to: “It shows there is no directional dependence. “,

Yes, but this have nothing to do with symmetrical kinematical time dilation!

From the viewpoint of the earth clock, we see the Muon moving towards earth at a speed close to light speed. As the Muon is approaching earth (and not moving away from earth as in the outbound journey of the twin paradox), the velocity is negative and from the viewpoint of earth the clock of the Muon should be speeded up (time contraction, not time dilation)!

Comment: From the viewpoint of the Muon, however, it is really standing still and earth is approaching at a speed close to light speed! So the Muon will see the earth clock speeding up (time contraction) - this would be symmetrical kinematical time dilation. But of course, we know that the presence of  Muons have absolutely no influence on the earth clock! 
Hence we have to reject the viewpoint of the Muon (that it really is at rest with respect to earth), otherwise we are left with a physically absurd interpretation.
So we know that the Muon is really moving towards earth (and not the other way)!

Comment: In 1905 Einstein and others did not have access to an instrument that can clearly tell who is moving near earth.
Fortunately, we now have a GPS receiver that can clearly tell us who is moving with respect to the surface of the earth. If we imagine the Muon travelling towards earth at close to light speed, with a miniature GPS receiver alongside the Muon, it will be clear that it is the Muon actually moving towards earth (and not the other way around)! So asymmetrical kinematical time dilation will always be observed - just as in GR.